# Calculate sum of merged rows and display in third column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to calculate the monthly expenses from my table.

[image: Sales table]

Want to sum up all the amount month wise and display in total like for January month total will be $180, March will be $230 and May $200. The amount should reflect in the total column. I have created this table using ng-repeat of angular framework (dynamic table)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7gzd4e2s/)

I have tried below code which will sum up all the individual cols having only numeric values. This code is not working for merged rows.

```
 for (col = 1; col < ncol + 1; col++) {
    console.log("column: " + col);
    sum = 0;
    $("tr").each(function(rowindex) {
      $(this).find("td:nth-child(" + col + ")").each(function(rowindex) {
        newval = $(this).find("input").val();
        console.log(newval);
        if (isNaN(newval)) {
          $(this).html(sum);
        } else {
          sum += parseInt(newval);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a data-month attribute to the cell displaying the amount, it is not visible to users, but super helpful for you. Have a look at the solution below.

```js
function getMonth(month) {
  var monthCells = $("td[data-month='" + month  + "']"); // get all TDs with a data month attribute
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < monthCells.length; i++){ // iterate over the tds
   var amountCell = monthCells[i]; // get a td for given iteration
   var amountCellText = $(amountCell).text();  // get the text content
      sum += parseInt(amountCellText.replace(/\D/, "")); // in amoutnCellText replace anything that's not a digit into an empty string
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(getMonth("march"))
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td data-month="january">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td data-month="january">$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">March</td>
    <td data-month="march">$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-month="march">$30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td  data-month="may">$200</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: how to run this function for all the months after the page load?

Comment: You can create an array of all months, and call it in a loop, you can add another attribute to the month name cells, and based on this pick the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
vm.data = [
        {
            month: 'January',
            savings: [
                { amount: 100 },
                { amount: 200}
            ]
        },
        { 
            month: 'February',
            savings: [
                { amount: 300 },
                { amount: 400 }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

In html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.data">
        <td>{{row.month}}</td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                <tr ng-repeat="s in row.savings">
                    <td>${{s.amount}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>${{vm.getTotal(row.savings)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In JS:

```
vm.getTotal = getTotal;

function getTotal(savings) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(savings,
            function (row) {
                total += row.amount;
            });

        return total;
    }
```

The key here is data modeling so that you have a simple function in getting total. Hope it will help.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hDnN.png)